# How to produce five outputs, one low, shifted on clock edge. 74HC logic

Tags: 7400

I want to produce five outputs, one of which should be low, unless the circuit is in reset, when all should be high.

The repeating sequence, on a rising clock edge, should be:

```
      qqqqq
reset 01234 
  1   11111
  0   01111
  0   10111
  0   11011
  0   11101
  0   11110
  0   01111
      .....
  1   11111
  0   01111
  0   10111
```

Holding the circuit in reset should cause all outputs to be high.  When the reset is released the bit pattern should begin again from `01111`.

Can I do this is 74HC logic?  I've looked at shift registers, but one problem is that they have a "clear all" input, not a "set all".

Is there a different approach?

Comment: Like most of these things is easier to do it with a small mcu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a counter (74xx163) and a decoder (74xx138).  The decoder's 0 output goes nowhere, and the next 5 outputs (1 through 5) are the desired 5 output bits. 6 and 7 are unused.  The counter's 3 LSBs go to the decoder's select inputs.  When the counter reaches a count of 5 it gets reloaded with a starting count of 1. The load input comes from the decoder's 5 output. A reset of the counter has it output a 0 count and the decoder outputs a 0, which isn't one of the output bits. When counter reset is negated, the count from 1 to 5 resumes.